# background shorthand not working if multibackgrounds

Tags: css, browser

I have the following CSS code:

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) url(bg1.png) top left/auto 50em repeat, url(bg2.png) top left/50% 100% no-repeat;
```

I think it's syntactically right according to [this w3schools reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp).

However, neither Chrome nor Firefox shows any background for the div it is applied to. What can be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### According to [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds):

> With CSS3, you can apply multiple backgrounds to elements. These are layered atop one another with the first background you provide on top and the last background listed in the back. Only the last background can include a background color.

```
selector {
  background: url(bg1.png) top left/auto 50em repeat,
              rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) url(bg2.png) top left/50% 100% no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: _"Only the last background can include a background color."_ That's the point I think. So all I need to do is to move that color to the second background.

Answer (score -1):

try with

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) url('bg1.png') top left 50em repeat, url('bg2.png')
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it's valid and it also lacks some information, e.g. the 50%.